# ControllerExceptionHandler not working on a spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller

I have a ControllerExceptionHandler with ControllerAdvise and when in application is thrown generalException or customException then i except to catch it in this ControllerExceptionHandler . But it doesn't happen. It looks very simple, read many sites , but it's not triggering.
Don't know where is the problem.

It's ControllerExceptionHandler.class

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<?> handleGeneralErrors(Exception e, UserPrincipal userPrincipal) {

        if (e instanceof ClientAbortException) {
            LOGGER.error("REST client abort: {}", e.getMessage());
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("REST controller error.", e);
        }

        //somelogic

        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseObject, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<?> handleCustomErrors(MyCustomException e, UserPrincipal userPrincipal) {
        LOGGER.error("MyCustomException error.", e);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(
            responseObject,
            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

Controller.class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/rest/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class Controller {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller .class);

@Autowired
private SomeLogicClass someLogicClass;


@GetMapping("/check")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<City>> list(UserPrincipal userPrincipal) throws Exception {
    //Some logic

    return ResponseEntity.ok(someLogicClass.handleRequest());
}
```

SomeLogicClass.class

```
    @Service
    public class SomeLogicClass{


    public void handleRequest() throws Exception {
        //some logic

        } catch (Exception ex) {
           throw new MyCustomException(); 
        }
    }
}
```

So, when the request is reaching SomeLogicClass, then some Exception(for example NPE) is thrown and then i want to throw in catch myCustomException. I expect that it will go to ControllerAdvise, but nothing and i see error 500.
Something is missing here or what? Controller and ControllerAdvise are located in some package.

I also tried to add the package

```
@ControllerAdvice("my.package.controller")
```

Comment: Well your `MyCustomException` is throwing a `INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` which is a `500`. Does that help?

Comment: Yes i understand you that is throwing INERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, but when i'm in debug it's not going inside of this method:

`@ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<?> handleCustomErrors(MyCustomException e, UserPrincipal userPrincipal) {
        LOGGER.error("MyCustomException error.", e);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(
            responseObject,
            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }`

I mean that i put breakpoint on this and it never stops on the line 

 `LOGGER.error("MyCustomException error.", e);`

Comment: I also changed the ResponseError to something else different from INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR and again i get 500 . It's not even reached the block.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found what caused that it skipped ControllerAdvise. The problem was UserPrinciple object, that is actually my custom class. Any custom class that i put additionally in input argument was a problem. I don't know the reason for this , but implemented without UserPrinciple.class.